# I am trying to create a function that takes in a vector of numbers and outputs a list of size N

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that takes in a vector (X) of numbers and outputs a list of size N.  This seems like it would be easy.  I must have something small wrong with my code.  When I ask for X to be described it tells my my function string, not the answer I am looking for.

```
X=c(15,23,49,72,12,9)
N=3

My.function=function(X){
return(list(0,nrow=length(N[1, ]),ncol = length(V.size)))
}
```

This is my first time writing a function so sorry if there are some really basic errors.

I am expecting to get a list that is 3 numbers long.  With the 3 numbers being any 3 from Vector X.

Comment: How do you want the vector to be split into 3 list elements?  In your function, `V.size` is not defined. and `N` seems to be different dimension that the one defined.

Comment: Oh sorry I was trying to make it simpler my changing names, then I ended up rewriting some of it.  My.function=function(X){
return(list(0,nrow=length(N[1, ]),ncol = length(X)))
}

Comment: You should show the expected output when you post.  In that way, it would be easier.

Comment: try `as.list(sample(X, N))`

Answer (score 0):

That should do it.

```
X=c(15,23,49,72,12,9)
N=3

myFun=function(X){
  as.list(X[1:N])  
}

myFun(X)
```

The part

```
X[1:N]
```

creates the subvector `c(15,23,49)` and `as.list` does what one would expect.

Comment: When I try to run this code I end up getting:   > myFun
function(X){
  as.list(X[1:N])   Instead of a list like I would expect.

Comment: run `myFun(X)` afterwards